# How do I make pictures/wallpapers suitable to be printed into A0 posters?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, posters

I've got several wallpapers 1920x1080, 2048×1080 resolution, as well as smaller pictures that I want to make suitable (i.e. quality, resolution, etc) to be printed into A0 posters.

I have access to Adobe image manipulation products if that's necessary.

How do I go about that?

Well, I guess Google can help.

Went from [image]     to    [image]    ...

Yes, I might've overdone it a bit. But I'm happy with it to print on an A3/A2 poster. I'm not entirely satisfied how the eye came out, but I can only do so much with Illustrator. I'm no graphic designer.

Comment: Unfortunately fairy godmothers and wishing wells do not exist.

Comment: Hi Grumpy ol' bear, can you tell us what you have tried and why that didn't work. You say you have Adobe image manipulation products, are you planning to do this in Photoshop? Making pictures "Suitable" is somewhat vague. You can certainly upscale an image using the 10% trick but the image will end up pixelated.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60323/large-format-photograph-printing/60534#60534

Comment: possible duplicate of [What resolution should a large format artwork for print be?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be)

Comment: I haven't tried anything, 'cos I have no idea how and where to start. It just something I wanted to do and experiment around privately as a fun side-project. I'm not a graphic designer, but I do know my way around a little bit, so I thought that'd be a good start. Apparently I'm in the wrong Stackexchange...it used to be about Q&A, now it's just like these job descriptions. In order to ask a question in any Stackexchange, you have to have an advanced degree, 50000 hours of practice, preferably 3-5 years of experience and more. Closed this question, delete it, whatever floats all y'all's boats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot achieve this with your current reference files and maintain a pleasing level of quality.

You could try to find these images on a stock website or contact the owners, distributors, licensees, etc and purchase a higher MB file size. Preferably no less than 15-25 MB depending on your definition of good quality.

Her is why:

The A0 paper is approx. 33w x 46l

The desktop resolutions will not put enough ink per inch (see 10dpi) for comparable size using these resolutions.

With your current files you may produce a reasonable quality print (see 150 dpi), but it would be no bigger than 13w x 7l. Increasing the quality (dpi) decreases the printed size.

Sorry that's not what you want to hear.

Comment: I also wanted to leave you with this link for future reference - I forgot to add it to the post!

http://toolstud.io/photo/megapixel.php?width=2048&height=1080&compare=video&calculate=print

Comment: MB is not by any means measure of either quality or size.